# Change value of field in reactjs component's state (with data obtained from firebase)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I simply want to fetch a string from a Firebase database and update the "eventName" field in my component, but I'm having trouble doing this.
My code so far:

```
import React from 'react';
import {ref} from '../Firebase';

class EventDisplay extends React.Component {
    constructor () {
        super();
        this.state = {
            eventName: "No event Selected."
        };
    }
    render () {
        return (<div>
            <h1>Name of Event: {this.state.eventName}</h1>
            <h1>Date and Time: Dummy Name</h1>
            <h1>Event Description: Dummy Name</h1>
        </div>);
    }

    changeEventName(str) {
        this.setState({eventName: str});
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        const events = ref.child('events/event1/Title');
        var param;
        events.on('value', (function(snapshot) {
            param = snapshot.val();
            console.log(snapshot.val());
            changeEventName(param);
            })
        );
        console.log(param);
    }


}

export default EventDisplay;
```

However, changeEventName seems to be undefined where it is. Also "undefined" shows up in the console where I try to log param, but snapshot.val() has the desired string.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> changeEventName seems to be undefined where it is

Where you're calling `changeEventName` you need to prepend it with `this`.

```
this.changeEventName
```

Also since you're calling it inside of a callback you first need to bind the method in order to preserve the value of `this`. There're many ways you can do this, most common being:

Explicitly inside of a constructor:

```
this.changeEventName = this.changeEventName.bind(this)
```

Or using an arrow function:

```
events.on('value', ((snapshot) => { ... }));
```

> Also "undefined" shows up in the console where I try to log param

That's because `events.on` is asynchronous, you need to move your `console.log` inside of the callback.

Comment: thanks for the explanation; I used this.changeEventName and I got the error: this is null; luckily, i was able to fix this by changing my syntax to (snapshot) => {...

Comment: @David Ye, you first need to bind the method, check the updated answer with an explanation of why you need it

Answer (score 0):

Try `this.changeEventName` when invoking the function; you need to do this because the function is available only within the context of the class.

Logging `param` returned undefined because `events.on` is an asynchronous function. What that means is that this function will go do whatever it was designed to do (fetch value) and only then execute the callback when its ready; `param` is only available in this callback method that you provided.